# Zip files from a directory

Tags: linux, shell, zip

I need to find files i directory and zip them under the same name.

i am trying the following

```
find . -name "ABC_*.txt" -mtime +30 -exec sh -c zip '{}' '{}' \;"
```

But something is wrong.

basically if find command finds 3 files say:

```
./ABC_1.txt
./ABC_2.txt
./ABC_3.txt
```

I will need 3 zip files:

```
./ABC_1.txt.zip
./ABC_2.txt.zip
./ABC_3.txt.zip
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry. my answer was bad. didn't read your edit

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find . -name "ABC_*.txt" -mtime +30 -exec zip "{}.zip" "{}" \;
```

You are likely overwriting your original file and will need to supply an extension to your ZIP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `execdir` option:

```
find . -name "ABC_*.txt" -mtime +30 -execdir sh -c 'zip "$1.zip" "$1"' - '{}' \;
```